# Extensions to AUCTeX to be able to move up/down, promote and demote sections

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I remember having read something about extensions to AUCTeX which allow to move up or down chapters, sections, etc. ... even list items. Or to promote them / demote them in a way similar to what Org-mode is capable of.

Though, I can't find any information about that anymore. Did I dream?

Comment: If you are using RefTeX together with AUCTeX, you can promote and demote chapter/sections with `</>` in the window that appears with `C-c =`

Comment: Try this http://staff.science.uva.nl/~dominik/Tools/outline-magic.el

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outline-minor-mode` which then gives you `outline-demote` and `outline-promote`.

Comment: That's only "one third" of the problem: are there ways to invert 2 sections, or 2 list items?

Answer (score 0):

There is the outline-magic mode which extends the outline-minor mode so you can use it with auctex to move up/down or promote/demote chapters, sections,..., but not list items (to my knowledge!)

https://github.com/tj64/outline-magic.git